# Laravel 9 | cURL request to HTTP Client

Tags: laravel, curl, httprequest

New versions of laravel have their own HTTP client. I like the syntax and want to use it. Before that I was always using cURL.

I am now trying to make a request with the new HTTP client, but I always get a weird result back. Status is 200 btw.:

```
{
    "cookies": {},
    "transferStats": {}
}
```

I dont know where this comes from, my endpoint does not return this.

This is the cURL version, which works:

```
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => env('SCAMMER_CHECK_ENDPOINT'),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('auth' => $data['auth'],'authUserId' => $msd_user_id,'img' => $data['base64img']),
        ));

        $scammer_check = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
```

This is the same request with the HTTP client, which does not work:

```
        $scammer_check = Http::post(env('SCAMMER_CHECK_ENDPOINT'), [
            'auth' => $data['auth'],
            'authUserId' => $msd_user_id,
            'img' => $data['base64img']
        ]);
```

I also tried to use raw body, but same result:

```
        $scammer_check = Http::withBody(
            json_encode(array('auth' => $data['auth'],'authUserId' => $msd_user_id,'img' => $data['base64img'])), 'application/json'
        )->post(env('SCAMMER_CHECK_ENDPOINT'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the HTTP client is returning an empty response with cookies and transferStats. This could be due to incorrect response handling.

You could try retrieving the response body by using the "body" method on the response object like this:

```html
$response = Http::post(env('SCAMMER_CHECK_ENDPOINT'), [
    'auth' => $data['auth'],
    'authUserId' => $msd_user_id,
    'img' => $data['base64img']
]);

$scammer_check = $response->body();
```

Alternatively, you could try specifying the expected response format like this:

```html
$scammer_check = Http::post(env('SCAMMER_CHECK_ENDPOINT'), [
    'auth' => $data['auth'],
    'authUserId' => $msd_user_id,
    'img' => $data['base64img']
])->json();
```